# Mapping json using Retrofit

Tags: android, mapping, retrofit, response

I am having a problem with the following problem. I tried to google but was not able to find anything helpful.

I have to map a response coming from API using Retrofit. Can somone please provide sample for creating a response model class for this json?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level of your JSON response is an *array*, not an *object*. For Retrofit, you'd define a single class that represents each of the 18 inner objects, and then you'd make a call for `List<MyObject>`. The response will be a Java `List` holding 18 instances of `MyObject` (or however many items are in the array).

Comment: I dont want to manually map all of those 18 objects. Can I get all of them as a list?

Comment: Perhaps my phrasing was unclear. You define only one class (MyObject), that represents a single item in the list. You then simply make a `Call<List<MyObject>>` (as opposed to a `Call<MyOuterObject>`) and you will get a list of any number of `MyObject`s.

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot about Call<List<>>. Could please also inform me that what happens if similar issue exists within this one of 18 objects. What should I do then?

Comment: The same thing. Any time you have a JSON array, you can use `List` to represent it in your pojos. Maybe `MyObject` has a field that is `List<String>` or `List<MyOtherObject>`.